# import module from src itself in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

How can I do import a file from src folder itself.

My aliases work fine say

```
import Button from 'components/button';
```

assuming  components is directly under src.

Similarly I'm many level deep inside another folder and want to refer something in root. How can I do this?

```
import { store } from '@';
```

which is currently like

```
import { store } from '../../../../../index';
```

Comment: You could try to add this: https://github.com/entwicklerstube/babel-plugin-root-import

Comment: If you've setup imports with NODE_PATH=src, then you can just import from 'index'.

Comment: I haven't. That's a n older technique now. It's available in docs now if you want to look

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following which always worked from me. For example, the `shared` folder is directly under the `src` folder. And I do the following:

```
import Checkbox from 'shared/common/components/input/Checkbox';
```

The way imports works are mainly in 2 ways. Either relative, which is the way you were doing up until now, and the absolute, which is declaring the path from the `root`.

Comment: Please check my answer and try to do that.